# Need support for fixxing issue with Regex [A-Za-z\s/.+-], receive \n in front of string after execting

Tags: regex, space

I want to extract possitions names from one column and for that goal use regex - [A-Za-z\s/.+-]
It gives me \n before every possition name.
\nBackend Development',
\nJava',
\n.NET',
\nPHP',

Issue is comming from \s, when remove it output is correct but when have space script is dividing position:
'Backend',
'Development',
'Java',
'.NET',
'PHP',
'C/C++/Embedded',
'Python',

Could you please support me fixxing of that issue.

```
import re

# Given data
data = """
Backend Development716
Java248
.NET152
PHP80
C/C++/Embedded70
Python57
Ruby8
Go22
Node.js52
Infrastructure318
DevOps130
Database Engineer54
Cybersecurity63
SysAdmin36
Mobile Development73
iOS28
Android36
Hardware and Engineering58
Frontend Development298
JavaScript288
React124
Angular58
Vue.js9
Quality Assurance148
Automation QA108
Manual QA21
Data Science178
ETL/Data warehouse37
Big Data5
BI/Data visualization36
ML/AI/Data modelling51
Customer Support67
Fullstack Development143
PM/BA and more219
IT Project Management58
IT Business Analyst33
Product Management26
Product Owner18
Tech Writer5
ERP / CRM Development108
SAP69
SalesForce18
UI/UX, Arts59
Technical Support91
"""

# Filter out strings without numbers using regular expression
strings_without_numbers = re.findall(r'[A-Za-z\s/.+-]+', data)

strings_without_numbers
```

Comment: Replace `\s` with the literal space character? `re.findall(r'[A-Za-z /.+-]+', data)`? Or, if you also want to match tabs, put `\t` right after space, too.

Comment: You can greatly simplify this by running `data.splitlines()` before any other processing

Comment: I used space character and it is working. I did not now that can use it because in presentations that I learn is written \s. Thank you soo much.